# PowerBI Desktop report not showing correct data when published to PowerBI server

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

When I upload the report to PowerBI server, I am not getting the exact result as PowerBI desktop. I am not sure where I am making the mistake. I have created a measure and I am applying conditional count based of a column and it's values.

My DAX is here:

```
TOTAL CLIENTS = CALCULATE(COUNT(AbpTenants[Customers]),FILTER('AbpTenants',[Customers] = "false-1")) + 0
```

But When Publish to the server, then It always becomes zero. I don't know what's the issue.

Here is the Table Column where I am counting only "false-1"

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you published dashboard more than 1 time ? then ty to delete data source, report form tenant and republish it

Comment: Hi @Dilantha . Thank you so much for your reply. Yes, I have published several times. I have deleted the whole report & dataset along with Workspace from powerbi.com but still the issue is there. Where can I delete "report form tenant" as you mentioned above?. Does that mean to delete the report and dataset? . I already did that.

Comment: Yes, Usually we can try out few things, sometimes these things happen,
Try delete report and dataset from myworkspace and republish it.

Try to full sync dataset from powerbi desktop , save before publish.

If you are using gateway you can try refresh dataset manually.

Comment: Usually these try out works,
If not you can add question here power bi community,
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/bd-p/power-bi-designer


they are professionals who works in powerbi support

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and reply. Really appreciated. The problem is now sorted. The issue was with the "true/false". When the report was published to powerbi.com, it was converting automatically the "true" to 1 and "false" to 0, however, the value was becoming "0-2" and my filter was based on "false-2". I noticed this when I populated the columns data in the table on powerbi.com.